# jQuery plugin: Making a function on '$'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, prototype

I've made a small scrollbar jQuery plugin.  It has a pretty standard implementation: `$(selector).drollScroll({options});`, complete with default values.  The trick is that I'd like the user to be able to set these defaults ahead of time, so that for larger sites (I'm developing this for a larger site) future users can easily get identical scrollbars without specifying the parameters each time.

**I'd *really* like to allow the user to do this without first instantiating a jQuery object, so via something like `$.drollScrollDefaults({options})`.**

So far I have this:

<sub>(slimmed down to only the essentials for your reading pleasure)</sub>

```
(function($)
{
    var defaults = {
        content                :   ".drollScrollBowl",
        scrollBoxClassName     :   "drollScrollShoal",
        scrollbarClassName     :   "drollScrollPole",
        thumbClassName         :   "drollScrollTrollThumb",
        scrollbarOpacity       :   1,
        scrollbarFadeTime      :   300,
        scrollbarTimeToLive    :   1000,
        alwaysVisible          :   true,
        autoFade               :   false,
        overrideBoxStyling     :   false,
        overrideBarStyling     :   false,
        overrideThumbStyling   :   false,
        scrollWidthConstant    :   false
    };

    $.drollScrollDefaults = function(options)
    {
        $.extend(defaults, options);
    };

    $.fn.drollScroll = function(options)
    {
        var opts;

        return this.each(function()
        {
            // we want opts to be its own object in case someone edits it later
            opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            $(this).data("drollScroll", {options : opts});
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now this actually works, but **this** line

```
$.drollScrollDefaults = function(options)
```

seriously can't be how it's supposed to be done.  It feels hacked; I feel like I must be doing it wrong, like I should be using the (totally mystical to me) prototype of $ or something.  **Is this it?  Am I right already?  What *is* the best way to achieve this?**  Should I even be doing this!?

Comment: `$` is just an alias for `jQuery` which is on the `window` object at global scope. So, setting `$.myFunction` is no different than `$['myFunction']` which is no different than setting a property of any Javascript object.

Comment: I just felt like it should be more methodical, I guess.  Maybe I should spend some more time trying to understand how prototypes work in Javascript to help reassure myself when I *don't* need them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it, it's no worse than assigning global functions like my use of `window.number_format` (I build my own toolkits). Since you want the user to be able to call `$.drollScrollDefaults`, then that's what you should assign to.

Answer (score 1):

I usually define it on the function, for example,

```
$.fn.myplugin = function() { ... your plugin here ... };
$.fn.myplugin.defaults = { ... defaults here ...};
```

primarily because most of my plugins can be called both as `$.myplugin` and `$().myplugin()`

Access it within your plugin and outside with `$.fn.myplugin.defaults`

Comment: It allows the user to set defaults without initializing a jQuery object, as asked directly in the question. Essentially the same thing as defining it as a separate namespace, without taking up that extra namespace.

Comment: It's the same concept that you would use when setting the defaults of a jQuery UI Widget. you would override/extend the `$.ui.mywidget.prototype.options`.

Comment: This is really good information, but I think I have to go with @Kolink on this one.  I mean, I guess technically it doesn't *not* answer my question, but I blame that on the vague nature I gave it (sorry guys).  I **DO** think I am going to rewrite my plugin to use this style.

Comment: More precisely, i actually use $.myplugin.defaults, but that isn't as good of an option if you aren't defining a `$.myplugin` namespace already.